# RegEx Оставить нужный текст

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть два кода на разных страницах.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как из них:

```
<select name="selShade" id="selShade" style="width: 100%;" onchange="changeProduct(this.value,'', 'Crystal')"> <option value="102804" selected="">13" x 17" x 10" Natural Paper </option> <option value="102805">13" x 17" x 11" Silk </option> } </select>
```

и

```
<select name="selShade" id="selShade" style="width: 100%;" onchange="changeProduct(this.value,'', 'Crystal')"> <option value="102804">13" x 17" x 10" Natural Paper </option> <option value="102805" selected="">13" x 17" x 11" Silk </option> } </select>
```

оставить только текст после "selected="">" и до " "
Т.е. в первом случае Natural Paper, а во втором Silk

Сейчас использую:

```
selected="">.*"([a-zA-Z ]+)</option>
return $1
trim
```

но в обоих случаях остается "Silk"

Код №3:

```
<select name="selFinish" id="selFinish" style="width: 100%;" onchange="changeProduct(this.value,'' , this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)"> <option value="102808" selected="">Antique-Burnished Brass</option> <option value="162132">Sheffield Nickel</option> </select>
```

Comment: а так `selected="">[^<]*"([a-zA-Z ]+)?<\/option>`

Comment: Хватит, слышите, хватит пытаться решать такие задачи с помощью регулярных выражений. Используйте нормальный HTML парсер и выбирайте нужные элементы.

Comment: Какой посоветуете?)

Comment: Выбор парсера зависит от языка программирования, который вы используете.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/selected.*?\s*([a-z](?:[a-z ]*[a-z])*)\s*</gi
```

Пример работы https://regex101.com/r/jT0wJ7/1

В регулярке пытаемся выделить подстроку начинающуюся и заканчивающуюся английской буквой и из них же состоящую + пробел;

Подстрока может обрамляться пробелами;

После нее идет символ `<`;

До нее в обязательном порядке должно встречаться слово `selected`;

И основная хитрость в ленивом `.*?` переборе символов после слова `selected`.

Ну и модификаторы `g`(если нужен) и `i` тоже не забываем.

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш вариант подходит, вот только обнаружил, что к одному из форматов не подходит... Посмотрите, пожалуйста, Код №3. Я его добавил в тело вопроса. Заранее благодарю Вас.

Comment: @user5483600, https://regex101.com/r/jT0wJ7/2 P.S. Вопрос следует формировать полно сразу.